# VSTEST /LISTTEST has different result on different machines

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, powershell, selenium, nunit

I'm running the following PowerShell commands on the same DLL on 2 different machines.

```
$VStestConsoleExe = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe"
$TestDllLocation = "C:\Projects\**\**\Automation.Tests.dll"
& "$VStestConsoleExe" $TestDllLocation /ListTests /UseVsixExtensions:true
```

The problem is I have different list on each machine!

- I'm using `NUnit Adapter 3.4.1.0` on both machines for test
  discovery.
- Unit Test are using Selenium.
- I have the whole project on the 1st machine while only DLLs on the
  2nd one.
- I'm grouping by Traits in VS .

Comment: This doesn't sound like a powershell issue, rather environment differences between the two machines.

Comment: yes, makes sense! I'm just stating all the details as i can't quite figure out where is the config difference :S